# Why did my reputation drop 10 points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)

A question that I either answered or commented on at Stack Overflow was deleted and my reputation dropped 10 points. Why?

Since the question is deleted, I can't even look at what I wrote, so how can I improve?

Comment: On StackOverflow? The entire question [Full Time Employee versus Contract Work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201088/full-time-employee-versus-contract-work/201225#201225) was closed as off topic and deleted. Not just your answer.

Comment: You lost rep from an upvote. Deleted posts don't affect your rep at all, when the post is deleted any rep gained or lost is removed.

Comment: Wow, it seems very silly to be penalized in this way. How did I know the question was going to be deleted?

Comment: @user132221 - You aren't penalised. The net effect is neutral. You gained a +10 earlier from the upvote and then have a -10 later when the delete cancels it out which adds up to zero.

Comment: Ha, okay. Even this question got a -1. I'll be more judicious about interacting with the site.

Comment: Not sure why you need to be "more judicious". An off-topic question was removed. You weren't penalized for that, you just can't earn reputation from something that is off-topic because then reputation would be meaningless.

Comment: @Cody - I think he was talking about this question. He misunderstood events, and was belittled with down votes. Same happened here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142194/i-thought-downvoting-was-free-now. Also see Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at your [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4241/mmcglynn?tab=reputation) and see the exact reason for the reputation change.

Looking at that page, you can see the change on Feb 22 where it shows the -10 due to a deleted post.

This activity being visible in your reputation history is a result of [these recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there certainly must be questions around but I didn't find any. Anyway, trying to be as simple as possible: *if you post an answer (receiving upvotes/downvotes) on a question that gets deleted, your reputation will be restored as that question "never happened".*

This was usually confirmed through a recalc, but from now on, [it'll work a bit differently.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319/176533).