# I thought downvoting was free now

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Today I downvoted this answer and for some reason I got a -1. This was the first time this happened and I've been a member for about two months now.

Acording to [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927) downvotes were made free a while back. Did you guys just revert that policy three minutes ago?

```
-1   2 mins ago downvoted   -----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downvotes on **questions** are free. Downvotes on answers aren't, nor were they ever.

[Community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answers are an exception.

Comment: Ahhh. That makes sense.

Comment: You see. Don't ever promise free stuff. They start to think everything's free.